# Limits in switch cases in case range

Tags: case, d

I'm trying to include UTF-8 identifiers in a case switch but I get this error:

> Error: had 399 cases which is more than 256 cases in case range

D code:

```
    switch(value)
    {
        case 'a': ..  case 'z':
        case 'A': ..  case 'Z':
        case 0xC0: .. case 0x24F:
```

Why did the compiler impose such a limitation? for optimazation purposes? can I overcome it?

Comment: What is the code executed in each case?

Comment: otherwise the jump table gets too large

Comment: Break the `switch` into ranges with `if` statements, so you only have, say, 64 `case` statements per `switch`.

Comment: Anyone know if this is an implementation detail or not?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: In this case there's only one code to be executed. But why does the code to be executed matter?

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Is it in the spec? I think it would be more appropriated make it as jump table (just like a good C optimizer does) as possible. Otherwise generate the code just like it I were wrote using if-else-if.if it is the real reason why such a limitation I see forcing my self to switch to ifs as a downside to language.

Comment: @HotLicks: Did you mean like L33TS's did in your answer or something else?

Comment: @Jack, there are very different ways of solving the problem. The best one much depends on your use case.

Comment: What is the type of the `value` variable btw?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: The point of my question was why it doesn't work and there's such a limitation.. I know I can rewrite it using `if-else-if`

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe: it is `dchar`. Both `0xC0` and `0x24F` can be hold in a variable of that type

Comment: You also asked: "can I overcome it?" which most answer have interpreted as a request to find a way to write that code.

Comment: I know. You're right. My mistake. It was in the sense of using switch...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing this as an answer to get more space.

The limitation you see here is not in the spec http://dlang.org/statement and ONLY applies to CaseRangeStatements in the compiler: src/dmd/statement.c line 3437 in the version I have:

```
if (lval - fval > 256)
{   error("had %llu cases which is more than 256 cases in case range", lval - fval);
    lval = fval + 256;
}
```

As a result, a fix would be to break that range up into several pieces and put them right next to each other:

```
        switch(value)
{
    case 'a': ..  case 'z':
    case 'A': ..  case 'Z':
    case 0xC0: .. case 0x14F: // this compiles
    case 0x150: .. case 0x24F: // since it is broken up
```

Then you handle them the same way.

The compiler source doesn't say why it has that check, but the github history says it was committed in response to this bug: https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3139

[s]So it is an implementation detail in the compiler to avoid an infinite loop.[/s]

EDIT: actually, the 256 check was before that, I read the patch wrong, Don added a check in addition to it. Looks like the 256 thing precedes github so I don't know why it specifically was added, but I'm still pretty confident it has to do with that loop and memory concerns, just compiler implementation details and bugs.

Comment: break it into several pieces is a good solution. Thanks. I will myself investigate why that.  I thought the dmd compiler did generate a jump table as possible (like a C optimizing does) otherwise it does generate code just like it were if-else-if. I haven't checked assembly output although.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to get rid of the limitation is to use an array of delegate, and to select which method to call using the character as selector. Then your switch would looks a bit like this:

```
void main(string args[])
{
    alias caseProc = void delegate();
    caseProc[1024] callTable;

    void numberProc(){}
    void latinProc(){}
    void otherProc(){}

    for(auto i = 0; i < callTable.length; i++)
    {
        if (i >= '0' && i <= '9')
            callTable[i] = &numberProc;
        else if ((i >= 'a' && i <= 'z') | (i >= 'A' && i <= 'Z'))
            callTable[i] = &latinProc;
        else
            callTable[i] = &otherProc;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of (cant remember what's generated to compute the offs) then `JMP offs` you have something like `MOV reg,CharValue` ; `ADD reg, tableOffset`; (optional params things);`CALL reg`. A bit slower but if the switch is not used in a performance-critical location then you can afford it. ANd obviously the table has to be initialized in a constructor...not each time it's used...

Answer (score 0):

A switch in D can only contain up to 256 cases. You have to change the entire way of doing this.

```
if (value >= 'a' && value <= 'z')
{
    // ...
}
else if (value >= 'A' && value <= 'Z')
{
    // ...
}
else if (value >= 0xC0 && value <= 0x24F)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or like this if you wish to handle all cases the same.

```
if (value >= 'a' && value <= 'z' || value >= 'A' && value <= 'Z' || value >= 0xC0 && value <= 0x24F)
{
  // ...
}
```